# How can I change the value of an input text of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I have a button and once that button has been clicked it will add an iframe code and it'll load it. I want to change the value of the input type text that has been loaded with the iframe.

I have managed to do this by typing this into the Chrome console:

`document.querySelector("...").value = "new text"`

but this only works when 'embed' is set from the JavaScript context menu on Chrome console.
How can I do it without that?

[Image: setting to 'embed' on JavaScript context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5WiZ.png)

I can not add any ids to the input etc.

Comment: WHat do you mean by "add an iframe code"? Do you want to change the source URL?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are talking about or a link to the page?

Comment: I think you want to edit the content of the iframe from your top page. If both pages aren't in the same domain, you won't be able to do that. And even if they are, it could be a poor design to do so, bypassing basic sandboxing and security stuff. If you want to edit the content of the iframe, maybe you need to think about whether you really need an iframe.

Comment: For call a url page data in your page we use to iframe  more https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp so for change in page constant its necessary both are same domain.